# trying to have a label hidden, yet have it reappear with a button click using python tkinter. The widgets are arranged using .place

Tags: python, tkinter, button

Here is a snippet of my code. Basically, I have a text label that I want to hide until the button is clicked. Upon pressing the button, the label should appear. I am able to have the button run the other functions, but not place the label back on screen. Any ideas why this isn't working?

```
Mg_to_Use = Label(frame1, text = "The Mg needed for \
the above solution volume is:", 
font =  DialogFont, fg = "blue")
Mg_to_Use.place_forget(relx = .5, rely = .46, anchor = 'center')

myButton1 = Button(frame1, text = "Submit",
command = lambda: [Mg_to_Use.place(relx = .5, rely = .46, anchor = 'center'), Mg_calc(), MgToGrams(), Mg2Use()],
font =  DialogFont, fg = "green") 
myButton1.place(relx = .5, rely = .35, anchor = 'center')
```

Comment: You shouldn't have any parameters in `place_forget`, but I can't reproduce your error, the Label does not appear until I press the button.

Comment: I strongly recommend using functions rather than lambda. Functions are much easier to debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just place label if only button is clicked not at first but only when button pressed, this will no longer need, `.place_forget()`.
Try to do like this:

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()

def f():
    b.pack()
b=Label(root,text="last")

c=Button(root,text="prees",command=f)
c.pack()

root.mainloop()
```